# Can't delete a dictionary from a list of dicts using del method

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to delete every dictionary that has a point value of 0 but when I run this code the object still remains. Is there a special case here why it won't delete?

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

# using json open the player objects file and set it equal to data
with open('Combined_Players_DK.json') as json_file:
    player_data = json.load(json_file)

for player in player_data:
   for points in player['Tournaments']:
       player['Average'] = round(sum(float(tourny['Points']) for tourny in player['Tournaments']) / len(player['Tournaments']),2)

for players in player_data:
    for value in players['Tournaments']:
        if value['Points'] == 0:
            del value

with open('PGA_Player_Objects_With_Average.json', 'w') as my_file:
    json.dump(player_data, my_file)
```

Here is the JSON

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Dustin Johnson",
    "Tournaments": [
      {
        "Date": "2020-06-25",
        "Points": 133.5
      },
      {
        "Date": "2020-06-18",
        "Points": 101
      },
      {
        "Date": "2020-06-11",
        "Points": 25
      },
      {
        "Date": "2020-02-20",
        "Points": 60
      },
      {
        "Date": "2020-02-13",
        "Points": 89.5
      },
      {
        "Date": "2020-02-06",
        "Points": 69.5
      },
      {
        "Date": "2020-01-02",
        "Points": 91
      },
      {
        "Date": "2019-12-04",
        "Points": 0
      }
    ],
    "Average": 71.19
  }]
```

I'm not sure why I can't use the delete value. I tried remove as well but then I was left with an empty object.

Comment: Even when I ```print(value['Points'] == 0)``` it returns true

Comment: You want `del players['Tournaments']` for the deletion to act on the dictionary & remove that entry, and not `del value` which only deletes the `value` name from the scope. See [the del stmt](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delete `value` with `del` while looping as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34238688/13676202), if you want to use `del`, you should delete the item by its index not the value it takes in the scope of the for loop, because as @MosesKoledoye said in the comments:

> You want `del players['Tournaments']` for the deletion to act on the
> dictionary & remove that entry, and not del value which only deletes
> the value name from the scope. See the [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) stmt.

When you're looping and you want to modify the list, you have to create a copy, as you can see in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). I suggest you to see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34238688/13676202) above, to see other ways to delete an element while looping. Try this:

```
for players in player_data:
    for i in range(len(players['Tournaments'])):
        if players['Tournaments'][i]['Points'] == 0:
            del players['Tournaments'][i]
```

I prefer to use better dictionary comprehension, so you can try this too:

```
player_data[0]['Tournaments']=[dct for dct in player_data[0]['Tournaments'] if dct['Points']!=0]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'Dustin Johnson', 'Tournaments': [{'Date': '2020-06-25', 'Points': 133.5}, {'Date': '2020-06-18', 'Points': 101}, {'Date': '2020-06-11', 'Points': 25}, {'Date': '2020-02-20', 'Points': 60}, {'Date': '2020-02-13', 'Points': 89.5}, {'Date': '2020-02-06', 'Points': 69.5}, {'Date': '2020-01-02', 'Points': 91}], 'Average': 71.19}]
```

Comment: Awesome that worked. Do you know why the way I was doing doesn't work? Is there like a special case or something

Comment: @AustinJohnson when you do `del value`, the *reference* to the dictionary gets deleted, but the dictionary object does not get deleted because the list still contains the reference to the dictionary object.

Comment: @AustinJohnson just added a little explanation of why you method wasn't working. Hope you find it helpful. Also, you could consider accept the answer :).